# Exclude tests with a specific selector in lein test

Tags: testing, clojure, leiningen

I have a suite of tests in my leiningen-based Clojure project.

I want to run *most* of them frequently, but I want to *exclude* those with the `:integration` selector because they are slow and flaky.

If I understand correctly there's a built-in `:only` selector in leiningen which will run only the matching tests:

```
lein test :only :integration
```

I want a `:not` selector which does the opposite (runs all except `:integration`).

```
lein test :not :integration
```

Is there a way to build this with the facilities provided by `lein test`?

I know I can write a fn like `(complement :integration)` and put it in the `:test-selectors` map in my `project.clj` but it'll be hard-coded to ignore `:integration` -- what I really want is a general `:not` that I can parameterize with a keyword, so I can ignore my `:slow` or `:flaky` tests in other circumstances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do it with keywords, since they are picked up by Leiningen as arguments. But you can create a custom test selector that you pass a string:

```clj
:test-selectors {:not (fn [m s] (not (contains? m (keyword s))))}
```

That you can call with `lein test :not integration` or `lein test :not flaky`.